# I need help to get the link for PHP 5.0.0 x64 (64 Bit) binary for Windows OS

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I need to get the legacy php application to run on my apache webserver but have failed to get  the php 5.0.0 binary x64 bit for window OS since the 32 bit binary is not supported for the apache program running on laragon server. *The client intends to use it on localhost to manage financials only thus it will not be deployed online.*
The old php web applications uses alot of old functions such as mysql_connect() which are deprecated. and I do not have enough  time to convert them to use mysqli_ * functions since the codebase is abit big and has alot  of disorganized project structure, so I decided to just run the project. this is a sample code from the codebase since most of the methods are deperecated.

```
$host           ="localhost";
        $user           = "root";
        $password       = "hey1234";
        $db             = "microsave";
        
        mysql_connect($host,$user,$password);   
        mysql_select_db($db);
        require_once("../mysql.class.php"); 
        $db =& new db_mysql("localhost", "root", "hey1234", $db);
```

I have tried the official PHP download sites but no success, I managed to get php 5.3.54 *64 bit binary only.
These are all the PHP links that I have tried to download the PHP 5.0.0 window 64 bit binary but failed to get the link

- https://windows.php.net/download/ https://museum.php.net/php5/
- https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=28996
- http://php.adamharvey.name/releases/
- http://phpweb.hostnet.com.br/releases/

Please help me to get the download link for binary php 5.0.0 64 bit

Comment: "I do not have enough time to convert them" Do you have time to fix a compromised server?

Comment: The insistence on a minor version of `.0.0` does not indicate much expertise in understanding the requirements or implications.

Comment: (Furthermore there are shims and conversion tools for dated codebases. Not to speak of your very `mysql.class.php` already providing a wrapper and thus simple transition.)

Comment: @ceejayoz, the web application is running on the localhost that and it will not be hosted, just someone managing their financials and was not paid for that work. just restoring window os

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP):

> Over time, PHP interpreters became available on most existing 32-bit and 64-bit operating systems, either by building them from the PHP source code, or by using pre-built binaries.[34] For PHP versions 5.3 and 5.4, the only available Microsoft Windows binary distributions were 32-bit IA-32 builds,[35][36] requiring Windows 32-bit compatibility mode while using Internet Information Services (IIS) on a 64-bit Windows platform. PHP version 5.5 made the 64-bit x86-64 builds available for Microsoft Windows.[37]

The version of PHP you want to run never had a 64-bit version for Windows.

Comment: Thank you, so it means that I need to get a wamp server of 32 bit to run on my 64-bit window machine.  I tested WampServer version 2.5 and it has php 5.5.12